# WPF Unbind all elements and their sub elements from any bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, memory-leaks, unbind

I want prevent some memory leaks base on binding to `Static` members or... in my `WPF` `Window`.

This window include many `UserControl` and `element` and has some `static` resource.
I know i should `unbind` the `bindings` to `Static` classes to prevent some memory leaks and i know this kind of `unbinding`:

```
BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(....);

BindingOperations.ClearBinding(...., ....);

Element.ItemsSource= null;
```

But my question is:

Do you know or recommend any *automatic* `Unbind` system (some classes and codes that works as a mechanism to unbind all elements to call it when required) to use it when we want close the window to make sure there is not any binding to any element in the `Window` or its `UserControls` and their `elements` and any `sub-elements`???

I am finding a *safe way* to use in the window closing event...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I dont believe there is an automatic way to do this, but I defined my own extension methods on `DependencyObject` for a this purpose.

```
public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> EnumerateVisualChildren(this DependencyObject dependencyObject)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject); i++)
    {
        yield return VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i);
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> EnumerateVisualDescendents(this DependencyObject dependencyObject)
{
    yield return dependencyObject;

    foreach (DependencyObject child in dependencyObject.EnumerateVisualChildren())
    {
        foreach (DependencyObject descendent in child.EnumerateVisualDescendents())
        {
            yield return descendent;
        }
    }
}

public static void ClearBindings(this DependencyObject dependencyObject)
{
    foreach (DependencyObject element in dependencyObject.EnumerateVisualDescendents())
    {
        BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u. I meant a mechanism like your solution that make the `unbinding all` as an automatic work. but what do you think about your code? Dose it work just in 2 level of `DependencyObjects`?

Comment: `EnumerateVisualDescendents` is a recursive function, see there: `child.EnumerateVisualDescendents()` in the inner foreach

Comment: Ou yes,  its is a recursive function. What is your feedback about performance of this code and its speed?

Comment: I didnt really test the performance directly, the only thing I can say is that I'm running a similar method (update all bindings) when opening each window in the application. There was no noticeable delay

Comment: Dominik I can't find `EnumerateVisualChildren` method. I use .Net 4.5

Comment: sorry, seems I forgot to add an extension method to the answer. I dont have access to my code right now, I'll add it in the evening

Comment: @RAM I just added the method at the top of the code